# Launchy and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, compatibility, launchy

Does any know if the great, free, open source file and application Launchy, supports Windows 7 32 and/or 64-bit version. I can find no information on the Launchy homepage or on the Source Forge website.

Comment: Why don't you download it and try it..?

Comment: Because he probably hasn't migrated yet and wonders if everything will still work.

Comment: Ah true. Well in general, if it works on Vista it works on 7.

Comment: Now if they'll just support the new Indexing API.

Answer (score 3):

It works fine for me on Windows 7 x64

Comment: Indeed, and 2.5 version just came out recently.

Comment: What about when you try to launch 64 bit programs?  There seems to be chatter that launchy has known issues running on 64 bit Windows 7.  Is this not the case anymore?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion Launchy would just run, but for accurate information whether the developers consider it fully supported and what things would(n't) work you should check or ask at the following site:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/launchy/forums/forum/451016